# Get URL from nsIWebProgress STATE_REDIRECTING

Tags: http, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

I am looking for a **simple solution** to catch any [window](/questions/tagged/window) re-directions (`301`, `302` etc.) to retrieve the corresponding [url](/questions/tagged/url) from a `nsiWebProgress`.

#### Current solution

Right now, I am using the `nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT` event listener, processing any `STATE_REDIRECTING` status responses (also known as "flags") and iterating the `responseHeaders` from the corresponding request's `nsIHttpChannel` interface , as shown below.

#### Question

However, I am not sure, if I am using the best event listener (`NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT`) and if this is really the *fastest* possible solution.

Furthermore, I am wondering, if [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) has processed any *validation* of the response's `location` header at this state, since I am tending to *parse* the `location` header by using the `sdk/url.URL` method, to be sure that the given `location` header is valid and no [xss](/questions/tagged/xss) scam.

---

Client request:

> ```
> GET /garage HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.batmans.cave
> ```

Server response:

> ```
> HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
> Location: https://batmans.cave/garage/batmobile
> ```

Working example (simplified):

```
const { Ci } = require("chrome");
const LOCATION_HEADER = "location";
```

...

```
interfaces: ["nsIWebProgressListener", "nsISupportsWeakReference"],
add(browser) {
   try {
     browser.addProgressListener(this, Ci.nsIWebProgress.NOTIFY_STATE_DOCUMENT);
   } catch (error) {}
},
```

...

```
/**
 * Called when the state has changed for the window being watched changes.
 * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/nsIWebProgressListener#onStateChange%28%29
 * @param {nsIWebProgress} webProgress
 * @param {nsIRequest} request
 * @param {nsresult} status
 * @param {String} message
 */
onStateChange(webProgress, request, status, message) {
  if (status & Ci.nsIWebProgressListener.STATE_REDIRECTING) {
    const window = webProgress.DOMWindow;

    if (request instanceof Ci.nsIHttpChannel) {
      const httpChannel = request.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
      let location;

      httpChannel.visitResponseHeaders(function (header, value) {
        if (header.toLowerCase() == LOCATION_HEADER) {
          location = value;
        }
      });

      if (location) {
        try {
          const url = URL(location).toString();

          console.log("redirect to", url); // OK! "https://batmans.cave/garage/batmobile"
        }
        catch (error) {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution, because you can load it into a specific tab. The other solution is http observers, but that is at a much higher level, you will have to filter out per tab.

Comment: This is how to use nsIWebProgressListener in a e10s safe way - https://github.com/Noitidart/Full-Stop